# How to break javascript operation on input and start new operation

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, filter

I have produced a table but I am using `<div>`s instead of `<tr>`s and `<td>`s. here is an example:

```
<div class="tbl tbl1">
    <div class="thead">
        <div class="tr">
            <div class="td colTitle" style="width: 120px"><span>Title</span></div>
            <div class="td colLink" style="width: 190px"><span>Link</span></div>
            <div class="td colSize numeric" style="width: 75px"><span>Size(MB)</span></div>
            <div class="td colUploadDate" style="width: 75px"><span>UploadDate</span></div>
            <div class="td colOpen" style="width: 50px; max-width: 50px;"><span>Show</span></div>
        </div>
        <div class="tr">
            <div class="td colTitle">
                <input type="text" class="Filter" />
            </div>
            <div class="td colLink">
                <input type="text" class="Filter" />
            </div>
            <div class="td colSize">
                <input type="text" class="Filter" />
            </div>
            <div class="td colUploadDate">
                <input type="text" class="Filter" />
            </div>
            <div class="td colOpen">
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
    <div class="tbody">
    </div>
</div>
```

I will fill `tbody` part with server-side operations.

I use below codes to filter my rows based on values entered in filter inputs.

```
$(".Filter").on('input', function () {
      filterGrid();
      $(".rowCount").val($(".tbody .tr:visible").length);
});
function filterGrid() {
    $('.tbody .tr').each(function () {
        var v = 1;
        var x = $(this);
        $(".thead .Filter[value!='']").each(function () {
            var i = $(this).parent(".td").index();
            if (x.children(".td:eq(" + i + ")").html().indexOf($(this).val()) == -1) {
                v = 0;
                x.hide();
                return false;
            }
        });
        if (v == 1) {
            x.show();
        }
    });
}
```

My code works fine when I have a few number of rows, but when the number of loaded rows increases it takes more time to do filtering operation.

when I enter the first letter I can't enter the second letter until the end of filtering based on the first letter. can I enforce javascript to break the operation and start a new one when I type ?

below is a sample of my table

[image: This is a sample of my table]

Comment: Can you post some example rows inside the `tbody` so we can see what the structure is like?

Comment: @CertainPerformance I attached a photo showing my table containing some data.

Comment: The first thing you should do is optimise your code. What you currently have is inefficient jQuery-heavy code and a horrible algorithm (that doesn't e.g. cache the results and recomputes only the column whose filter value changed). If that doesn't help and you really have thousands of rows, you will need to do the looping asynchronously and break if there's a new input.

Comment: Can you post the *actual HTML*? Pictures aren't very helpful, they don't show the HTML structure

Comment: a sample row:    <div class="tr" idattachment="1"><div class="td colTitle" style="width: 120px;">FirstFile</div><div class="td colLink" style="width: 190px;">uf1_1.png</div><div class="td colSize" style="width: 75px;">0.11</div><div class="td colUploadDate" style="width: 75px;">1397/12/13</div><div class="td colOpen" style="width: 50px;"><a class="link" href="uploads/uf1_1.png">Open</a></div></div>

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You have quite a lot of jQuery operations that, when put together over many rows, may take a not-insignificant amount of time. Rather than constructing lots of jQuery collections (which have some overhead) and re-calculating the index you're looking for on every iteration, consider using vanilla Javascript instead, which is far more lightweight. You can also create an array of the filter values and their associated index in advance, so you don't have to navigate through the DOM to find them every iteration:

```js
$(".Filter").on('input', function() {
  $(".rowCount").val(filterGrid());
});

function filterGrid() {
  const values = Array.from(
    document.querySelectorAll('.thead .Filter'),
    elm => elm.value
  );
  
  let rowsShown = 0;
  document.querySelectorAll('.tbody .tr').forEach((tr) => {
    const tds = tr.querySelectorAll('.td');
    const noMatch = values.some((value, i) => {
      if (!value) {
        return;
      }
      const td = tds[i];
      return !td.innerHTML.includes(value);
    });
    if (noMatch) {
      tr.style.display = 'none';
    } else {
      tr.style.display = 'block';
      rowsShown++;
    }
  });
  return rowsShown;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

RowCount: <span class="rowCount">1</span>

<div class="tbl tbl1">
  <div class="thead">
    <div class="tr">
      <div class="td colTitle" style="width: 120px"><span>Title</span></div>
      <div class="td colLink" style="width: 190px"><span>Link</span></div>
      <div class="td colSize numeric" style="width: 75px"><span>Size(MB)</span></div>
      <div class="td colUploadDate" style="width: 75px"><span>UploadDate</span></div>
      <div class="td colOpen" style="width: 50px; max-width: 50px;"><span>Show</span></div>
    </div>
    <div class="tr">
      <div class="td colTitle">
        <input type="text" class="Filter" />
      </div>
      <div class="td colLink">
        <input type="text" class="Filter" />
      </div>
      <div class="td colSize">
        <input type="text" class="Filter" />
      </div>
      <div class="td colUploadDate">
        <input type="text" class="Filter" />
      </div>
      <div class="td colOpen">
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="tbody">
    <div class="tr" idattachment="1">
      <div class="td colTitle" style="width: 120px;">FirstFile</div>
      <div class="td colLink" style="width: 190px;">uf1_1.png</div>
      <div class="td colSize" style="width: 75px;">0.11</div>
      <div class="td colUploadDate" style="width: 75px;">1397/12/13</div>
      <div class="td colOpen" style="width: 50px;"><a class="link" href="uploads/uf1_1.png">Open</a></div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

If that's not fast enough, you can use `for` loops instead of array methods, which will make things a bit faster (though more difficult to read).

If you have a *huge* number of rows in the `.tbody` and this still isn't fast enough, then you might consider adding a debouncer to the `input` listener, so that `filterGrid` is only called after, say, 200ms after the last character was typed, so that the big operation only occurs once you have at least a *bit* of confidence that the character that was just typed might be the last one the user wants to input (rather than running `filterGrid` after every single character typed):

```
let filterTimeout;
$(".Filter").on('input', function() {
  clearTimeout(filterTimeout);
  filterTimeout = setTimeout(() => {
    $(".rowCount").val(filterGrid());
  }, 200);
});
```

Comment: Also return the number of matches from `filterGrid` instead of that horrible `$(".tbody .tr:visible").length`

Comment: I would've kept the `tr.style.display = noMatch ? 'none' : 'block';` and done `rowsShown += !noMatch;`. But have an upvote anyway!

Comment: Perfect, this is really efficient.