# How to reduce jquery search time complexity

Tags: javascript, jquery

I am using jquery custom search. is it feasible to use this search 
if there are around 10 million entries.
 Please suggest some other search 
functionality .

Presently in my mind I am thinking about "Big data or Hadoop"
if it used for bulk  entries.

```js
$("#searchInput").on("keyup", function () {
          var value = $(this).val().toLowerCase();
          $("#itemTable tr").filter(function () {
                $(this).toggle($(this).text().toLowerCase().indexOf(value) > -1);
          
          
          });
          ar t1 = performance.now();
           alert("Call to doSomething took " + (t1 - t0) + " milliseconds.");
   });   // <---- The function you're measuring time for 

});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.2.4/jquery.min.js"></script>
<input class="form-control" id="searchInput" placeholder="Search...">
```

Comment: Maybe something like https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54973766/how-to-break-javascript-operation-on-input-and-start-new-operation/54974003#54974003 ? Debounce and ditch the jQuery

Comment: Your code has syntax errors

Comment: To get more people to help you, please don't use non-universal measurements like crore.

Comment: Just rendering a plain HTML page with 10 million items on it will slow down a browser with zero javascript, that is incredibly massive and you will have issues no matter what.  You need to conciser server-side searching instead.

Comment: This 'search' appears to be filtering a DOM tree.  I'm very skeptical that you could even download ten million rows worth of data  into the client, let alone render a ten-million row table, let alone filter it on the client.  You'll need to go server-side for this (but start with a plain old sql database; you're not at Big Data scale here.)

Comment: 10 million entries? How does the page even render?

Answer (score 0):

Ideally... don't use jQuery if speed is what you are after.  but, here's a quick version in jquery to make it work for now.

Basically, selecting element is expensive, so do as much of that outside of the `keyup` function as you can.  You were using the `.filter()` method incorrectly, it filters down a previous jQuery selector.

now when you type it shows everything, and hides everything that does **not** match.

```js
var $rows = $("#itemTable tr");
$("#searchInput").on("keyup", function() {
  $rows.show();
  var value = this.value.toLowerCase();
  var $rowsTohide = $rows.filter(function() {
    return $(this).text().toLowerCase().indexOf(value) === -1;
  });
  
  $rowsTohide.hide();
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.2.4/jquery.min.js"></script>

<input type="search" class="form-control" id="searchInput" placeholder="Search...">

<table id="itemTable">
  <tr><td>FOO</td></tr>
  <tr><td>bar</td></tr>
  <tr><td>baz</td></tr>
  <tr><td>hello</td></tr>
</table>
```